# Basic capacitor in circuit

Tags: transistors, capacitor, function-generator

I’m new with electronics. I really don’t know how to search up this circuit. This circuit will make the LED turn on when it has microphone input. Could someone explain or suggest what should I search to know how this works?

[image]

Comment: You have the circuit already. Why do you need to search for it any more?

Comment: Like I said, I’m new with electronics. My teacher just gave me this and didn’t tell me anything about it. I want to know how It works like why do we need capacitors in this circuit. And what does transistor do in this circuit

Comment: What is the specific relevance of the title (Capacitor and transistor) given that there are also resistors, LEDs and a battery? Why have you tagged it "function-generator"? You are already asking new questions in comments and that tells me that you need to go and study capacitors (and resistors and LEDs) to prevent this question being closed as requiring too many answers. Remember that this isn't a forum but a Q and A site so try and stick to putting relevant questions into the body of your question.

Comment: This site isn't really geared-up to tutor beginners in a linear and developing way within the constraints of one question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea why someone added C2 there.  It will probably stop the circuit working, and the + symbol is on the wrong side.

C1 is to block DC and let AC through.  It's one of the common uses of a capacitor.

Q1 is an NPN transistor.  It amplifies current.  Pass a small current from the base to the emiter, and it allows through a larger current from the collector to the emitter.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will learn more about it.